Wayland Fractional Scaling Problem
On Wayland Session in Ubuntu 24.04, I got some annoying issue.
Set scaling to 150%, It Looks good in xorg session. but in wayland, It's not clear as xorg.
only fractional scaling has problem.
I've found some posts that similar with mine, but I think it's different.
Not only non-native apps like steam, discord, Microsoft Edge. GNOME Apps icon is blurry too.
I'd like to use wayland with 150% scaling, please someone guide me how to fix this problem. Thank you. (And sorry for my bad english ;D)
Session Comparison With 150% Scaling. The left is wayland and the right is xorg.

Steam runs on XWayland, where fractional scaling is still an open issue. It will continue to be blurry as there's no simple workaround. For games that run through steam, you can use gamescope to prevent blurriness (it also substantially improves performance, due to how it handles scaling).
Discord and MS Edge are Electron apps, which do support fractional scaling. Try running them with --ozone-platform-hint=auto to force the Wayland backend. Some quick searching indicates that at least Discord is built with proper support.
If I recall correctly, recent versions of Electron enable Wayland support by default, so it might be a matter of these applications being built with an old Electron.

Thanks for response! As you said, Electron apps with arguments are works well and Steam too. Could you tell me way for the Unreal Engine?
